# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'. Error while generating the main dex list

Tags: pdf, dart, pdf-generation, dart-pub, dart-webui

I'm developing an application which generates a **pdf** and shares this **pdf** using Flutter & DART.

I'm importing a library called `share_extend: ^1.0.3` in my `pubspec.yml` file to share the generated pdf.

**sharePdf.dart**

```dart
async {
  String name='John';
  pdfGenerator(name);
  final String downloadPath= await getApplicationDocumentsDirectoryPath();
  final files=File('$downloadPath/$name.pdf').path;
  ShareExtend.share(files,'file');
},
```

> Error : Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.

Please can someone explain to me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: your dependency might be mismatching. I was having such an exception while using Toast and I then migrated the library to other one and the issue was resolved

Comment: yes  ,actually the main problem is this "The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app" and i didnt found any dependency for sharing file that is compatible with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to migrate your project to AndroidX.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: thanks it works for me by migration android to androidX